# Compilation issue between XCode versions (webkit)

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, webkit, xcode7

I have a class that is derived from NSView and wraps a WebView instance. This class is set as delegate for different parts (frame load, UI, policy and resource load). This compiles and works well with XCode 6.

After upgrading to XCode 7 I got errors, because the WebView's frameLoadDelegate etc. have been changed from just `id` to e.g. `id<WebFrameLoadDelegate>`. In order to make it compile again I changed the code to:

```
@interface WebBrowser : NSView <WebFrameLoadDelegate, WebUIDelegate, WebPolicyDelegate, WebResourceLoadDelegate> {
...
```

This compiles and works fine with XCode 7, but does not in XCode 6. Even though the delegates are defined there too and WebKit is included I still get errors that those delegates are unknown. What's the fix here to make it work in XCode 6 too?

I was thinking about wrapping the protocol part with an #if/#endif, but don't know what I could use as condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to silence the XCode 7 compiler (LLVM 7) by explicitly casting the delegate to `(id)`, instead of making the class implement the protocols.

```
- (instancetype)initWithObject: ...
{
  self = [super initWithFrame: NSMakeRect(10, 10, 10, 10)];
  if (self)
  {
    mBrowser = [[[WebView alloc] initWithFrame: [self frame]] autorelease];
    [self addSubview: mBrowser];
    [mBrowser setFrameLoadDelegate: (id)self];
    [mBrowser setUIDelegate: (id)self];
    [mBrowser setPolicyDelegate: (id)self];
    [mBrowser setResourceLoadDelegate: (id)self];
    [mBrowser setShouldCloseWithWindow: YES];
  }
  return self;
}
```